# Using custom android.jar with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a custom android.jar to use the Android hidden API for my projects. But I cannot add the library to the external libraries before Android SDK. In eclipse I can add the library and sort it before Android SDK. Is there a way to do this in Android Studio.

Here is an image to make my question clearer:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is easy to solve.
You need to go File -> Project structure, open Dependency tab and add File dependency.
[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr2BP.png)

Comment: I had tried this way, but Android Studio seems first to compile with Android SKD, not my custom jar.

Comment: @Sandi what is you want to get?

Comment: @Sandi : Is your problem solved ? Could you share the solution. Am facing the same problem.

Comment: I am facing same problem too